# Why shiny.router::router_server crashes in an helper function?

Tags: r, shiny

#### Context

I'm trying to use the [shiny.router](https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.router/index.html) package.

---

#### Working example

This example shiny app totally works and permits to route to another page when adding `other` to the URL:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.router)

root_page <- div(h2("Root page"))
other_page <- div(h3("Other page"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Router demo",
  router_ui(
    route("/", root_page),
    route("other", other_page)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  router_server()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

#### Twist that breaks code

But I cannot figure why moving the call to `router_server()` to an helper function breaks this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.router)

root_page <- div(h2("Root page"))
other_page <- div(h3("Other page"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Router demo",
  router_ui(
    route("/", root_page),
    route("other", other_page)
  )
)

helper <- function() {
  router_server()
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  helper()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

That raises this error:

```
Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  1: runApp
Warning: Error in observe: attempt to apply non-function
  1: runApp
```

---

#### Effort to solve the issue

The docs shows that router server needs a parent evironment: `router_server(root_page = "/", env = parent.frame())`

So I tried to pass it to the function like that:

```
helper <- function(env) {
  router_server(root_page = "/", env = env)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  helper(env = parent.frame())
}
```

But it does not change a thing to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this:

```r
helper <- function(input, output, session) {
  router_server()
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  helper(input, output, session)
}
```

Comment: Another solution with my setup: `helper(env = environment())` but your solution is cleaner and the new arguments of the helper function will be used in my real case.